# Looping through a nested array in javascript. Not able to display it

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to loop through a nested array but not able to display. I am new to Javascript any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```js
let shoppingList = [
  ['Shirts', 'Pants', 'Tie', 'Belt'], 
  ['Fruits', 'Vegetables', 'Spices', 'Utensils'],
  ['Toilet paper', 'Washing liquid', 'Brushes', 'Sponges']
];

//accessing the above array using for loop
for(let shoppingIndex=0; shoppingIndex < shoppingList.length; shoppingIndex++) {
  document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = shoppingList(shoppingIndex);
}
```

```html
<p> </p>
```

Comment: You should be using square brackets (`[ ]`) to read an item from an array, i.e `shoppingList[shoppingIndex]`

Comment: Shoppinglist is not a function. You dont want to call it `()` you want to access it `[]` => `shoppingList[shoppingIndex]`

Comment: String literals delimited with quotes cannot span more than one line.

Comment: Thank you did'nt see that mistake!!!  idiot I am :D. Works now properly.

Comment: I am not able to retrieve all the array's elements. Any solution for that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the list items using `[]`. Also at the moment you will only ever display the last array, to display all arrays you can use `+=` and instead of using `innerHTML` you can use `textContent` since you're simply displaying text with no HTML.

```js
let shoppingList = [
  ['Shirts', 'Pants', 'Tie', 'Belt'], 
  ['Fruits', 'Vegetables', 'Spices', 'Utensils'], 
  ['Toilet paper', 'Washing liquid', 'Brushes', 'Sponges']
];

//accessing the above array using for loop
for(let shoppingIndex=0; shoppingIndex<shoppingList.length; shoppingIndex++) {
   document.querySelector('p').textContent += shoppingList[shoppingIndex];
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: Thank you!! can you please explain me what does += do?

Comment: No problem, it means to append text to the existing text instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let shoppingList = [['Shirts', 'Pants', 'Tie', 'Belt'], 
['Fruits', 'Vegetables', 'Spices', 'Utensils'], ['Toilet paper', 
'Washing liquid', 'Brushes', 'Sponges']];

//accessing the above array using for loop
for(let shoppingIndex=0; shoppingIndex<shoppingList.length; 
shoppingIndex++) {
 document.querySelector('p').innerHTML +=  shoppingList[shoppingIndex] + '<br>';
}
```

```html
<p> </p>
```

You are accessing property using `()` access with [`[]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements), and if you want to print with next line concatenate using `<br>`